# How to extract a perspective-corrected rectangle shaped area from an image on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I need to extract a rectangle shaped area from an image on iOS. What I mean by this is if you take a picture of a piece of paper, for example, on a table with the iPhone camera, you'll end up with a trapezoidal shape. I need to extract that trapezoidal shape and transform it back into a rectangle.

The application here is to import a drawing done on special paper (with markings to help orient the software that will be extracting it) and show it on the iphone screen without the extraneous parts of the image. This is trial in photoshop but it needs to be automated.

I've found OpenCV, and a tutorial (link below), but the object detection in opencv would need to know the shape of the drawing which will change every time.

http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut6.html

Comment: bump. It's not a trapezoid; neither of the lines are parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting the corners of the trapezoidal shape in the image is the tricky part. One possible way to do it is to look for intersections of line segments in the edge image (assuming the color of the paper is different from the background) and pick four of those intersections which can give you a valid trapezoidal shape (check angles, ...).  You may need to use additional cues to find the correct trapezoidal shape.

If you manage to detect the four corners, the rest is easier. Just feed the four corners of the trapezoid and the corners of the destination rectangle to cvGetPerspectiveTransform to find the mapping matrix.